# Invalid argument for JS pop up in IE8

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

My popup definition doesn't work in IE8, but works in FF...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function popUp(url, width, height)
{
 window.open(url, url, 'height=1024'+ height +'&width=768'+ width);
}
//-->
</script>
<? if((int)$_GET[editcontent]!=0) { ?>
<script>  popUp("/refreshercms/structure/edit.php?pageid=<?=(int)$_GET[editcontent]?>");     </script>
<? } ?>
```

EDIT: fixed it.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
function popitup(url) {
newwindow=window.open(url,'name','height=1280,width=1024');
}

// -->
</script>
```

Comment: So, you're sorted? Please close this question if so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the second parameter for `open()` may only contain chars allowed for [#IDNAME](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#h-6.2)